# Docker for Wildfly and Mysql: Module for driver [com.mysql] or one of it dependencies is missing: [com.mysql]

Tags: mysql, docker, wildfly

I´m trying to create a `Dockerfile` with the following script:

```
FROM quay.io/wildfly/wildfly:26.1.3.Final-jdk11

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin admin --silent

COPY my-standalone.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/
COPY myapp.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
COPY mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar /opt/jboss/wildfly/modules/system/layers/base/com/mysqldatabase/mysql/main/
    
EXPOSE 8080 9990

# Run with custom configuration
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0", "-c","my-standalone.xml"]
```

In the my-standalone.xml I config my database as:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:7.0">
    <datasources>
        <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myapp" pool-name="myapp" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myapp?serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin&amp;useSSL=false</connection-url>
            <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
            <driver>mysql</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>root</user-name>
                <password>test</password>
            </security>
            <validation>
                <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                <background-validation>false</background-validation>
            </validation>
            <statement>
                <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
            </statement>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

If I start docker like: `docker build -t mein_image_name .` and afterwards: `docker run -p 8080:8080 mein_image_name` then I get this error message:

```
21:10:06,717 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "mysql")
]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0115: Module for driver [com.mysql] or one of it dependencies is missing: [com.mysql]"
```

Any idea what´s wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your module name is wrong, it should be com.mysqldatabase.mysql and you should also provide the module.xml for it